# Chart from dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-charts

I was making a graph from a dynamic chart using VBA. 
The Chart is coming as expected, however I want the X axis to show X values from columns only that contains data. Here it is showing all the columns including those that are not having any data.

Below is my code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim LstRw2 As Long
Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
   Set rng = Range("E2:O" & N)
  Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
  cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
  cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
"='Sheet1'!$F$11:$O$11"
End Sub
```

As of now it takes the xvalues from another sheet however I want to use the current worksheet for the values

[image]

In the added picture 2021,2022,2023 should not be showing for x axis since they do not have any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub MakeChart()
 Dim rng As Range, cht As ChartObject, LstRow As Long, i As Long
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, lastC As Long, ColAddr As String
  Set sh = ActiveSheet      'use here your sheet
   LstRow = sh.Cells(Cells.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
   'Last column on the third row
   For i = 2 To LstRow
        lastC = sh.Cells(i, Cells.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
        If lastC > lastCol Then lastCol = lastC
   Next i
   ColAddr = sh.Cells(1, lastCol).Address 'last column address (on first row)

   Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Range("E2"), sh.Cells(LstRow, lastCol))
   Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(left:=100, top:=80, width:=350, _
                                                                height:=250)

   cht.Chart.SetSourceData source:=rng
   cht.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    sh.ChartObjects(sh.ChartObjects.count).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
                                            "='" & sh.Name & "'!$F$1:" & ColAddr
End Sub
```

I updated the code to use the longer row of the range, in order to set which values to be used from `Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues`...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru Thank you for your help the macro is working perfect for more than one rows, but when there is only a single row it is not working. Can you please help

Comment: A single row?  Please show us how your data range looks in such a case..  When I will be home I will solve it... Try changing of 'lastCol = sh.Cells(3, Cells...'  with 'lastCol = sh.Cells(lastR,ow, Cells'...

Comment: By Single row I mean to say, if you see the above picture there are two rows of data for which your macro is giving a perfect graph. I want the same graph when there will be one row, but it fails at that time. Could you please help me. Attaching link of the image that i am getting for one row https://drive.google.com/open?id=15S9BFM-f7EdbRllVFJQOfSj06DwzA91y

Comment: So basically for a single row the graph will be of 1 series. But it gives no graph as  you will see in the attached link.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked I just made a little change to your code. lastCol = sh.Cells(2, Cells.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column you are a genius. Thanks again

Comment: @bishwarup990: I tried to answer your question as it was made... You did not say anything about some extra rows... I am afraid that it works well now **only if the last row is the one having maximum of used columns**. I will adapt the code to calculate the column number for all rows and use the biggest one...

Comment: @bishwarup990: I adapted the code in the way I above explained...